# Using IntentService instead of AsyncTask for Broadcast Receiver?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-asynctask, intentservice

I am in the process of trying to get an email sent using BroadcastReceiver, the code is working correct using AsyncTask when using onClick but does not work when AlarmReceiver is being called.

Would it be better to use IntentService for this method? If so, what is the best way to write this?

Can anyone help with this problem? I am still new to java and want to help improve my knowledge. :)

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

**AlarmReceiver.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import static android.graphics.Color.GREEN;

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

Context cxt;
Activity context;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

    cxt = arg0;

    addNotification();
    new SendMail().execute();
}


private class SendMail extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        Mail m = new Mail("youremail@gmail.com", "password");

        String[] toArr = {"toemail@outlook.com"};
        m.setTo(toArr);
        m.setFrom("fromemail@gmail.com");
        m.setSubject("Achieve Alert!");
        m.setBody("This is a reminder about your upcoming assignment or examination!");

        try {
            if(m.send()) {
                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: yes, start intent service from Wakefulbrodcast and do not use asynctask in service

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How would i do this? I am still very new to java and still learning at this point.

Comment: override WakeFullBrodcastReceiver and inside of onmessage Received start IntentService class.

Comment: Thanks, are you able to give an example of this so i can understand clearly in replace of using AsyncTask for the method SendMail();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First start Intent service from Alarm manager :

```
 private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal){

   /* HERE */     Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmService.class);
        final int _id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

      /* HERE */  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this,_id,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    ......
    .....
```

Now Intent Service class:

```
 public class AlarmService extends IntentService {

PowerManager powerManager;
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

public AlarmService() {
        super("");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "FCFCFCFC");

        wakeLock.acquire();

       addNotification();
       sendMAIL();

    }


    public void addNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_transperent)
                    .setLights(GREEN, 700, 700)
                    .setContentTitle("Achieve - Alert!")
                    .setContentText("This is a reminder for your deadline!");

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMenu.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,     notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    // Add as notification
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    builder.setVibrate(new long[] { 0, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 });
    manager.notify(0, builder.build());
}

    public void sendMAIL(){

    Mail m = new Mail("youremail@gmail.com", "password");

        String[] toArr = {"toemail@outlook.com"};
        m.setTo(toArr);
        m.setFrom("fromemail@gmail.com");
        m.setSubject("Achieve Alert!");
        m.setBody("This is a reminder about your upcoming assignment or examination!");

        try {
            if(m.send()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e);
        }


        wakeLock.release();

    }


     @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Now, Manifest add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

<service android:name=".AlarmService" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i have tried what you posted but when the time is reached nothing is triggered, no notification to the device or email. No errors either. I have made sure to also include the code into the manifest. Could it be that AlarmService does not extends BroadcastReceiver anymore? I am not sure why nothing is being triggered.

Comment: No need to use brodcast receiver. Have you restart device? Post your newer code

Comment: Ahh ok, thanks. I have now updated my original post with what i have added under - Possible working code -

Comment: The error i am getting in logcat is:   03-18 15:51:00.660 1533-1577/system_process W/ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.example.pc.achieve/.AlarmService (has extras) } U=0: not found

Comment: Try to put whole service name in menifest instead of .AlarmService

Comment: I have done this, an error is shwon in logcat when the timer is reached, which is:  FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[]
                                                                        Process: com.example.pc.achieve, PID: 14453
                                                                        java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10082 nor current process has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK.

Comment: at com.example.pc.achieve.AlarmService.onHandleIntent(AlarmService.java:29)

Comment: It is referring to this in AlarmService.java   wakeLock.acquire();

Comment: After removing wakeLock.acquire(); the alarm is now sending an email automatically. Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Wake lock requires when you device is in sleep. You forgot to add permission in menifest thats why above error occured.

Comment: I included <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/> and still had the error.

Comment: Tried again and error:  java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10083 nor current process has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK. at com.example.pc.achieve.AlarmService.onHandleIntent(AlarmService.java:31)

Comment: Yes, without the code works fine and email is sent automatically when timer is reached.