# Refresh Android app in background every 30 seconds for Push Notification\

Tags: java, android, push-notification

I am working on Push Notifications for my Android App. I am using the below function to get Notifications. It is working fine when i click on particular button. For testing purpose, i performed this on button. Now, I would like to run this activity every 30 seconds.

Here is the code:

```
`public static void createNotification(Context mMain, boolean isLoggedIn)
    {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(mMain)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("Items in your Cart")
                        .setContentText("You have some pending items in your cart")
                        .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                        .setAutoCancel(true);
        int NOTIFICATION_ID = 12345;

        Intent targetIntent = new Intent(mMain, MainActivity.class);
        targetIntent.putExtra("isTrackOrder", false);
        if(isLoggedIn)
            targetIntent.putExtra("isLoggedIn", true);
        else
            targetIntent.putExtra("isLoggedIn", false);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mMain, 0, targetIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) mMain.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
    }`
```

Now What i want to do is, when i run the app or the app is running in background I want to call this function and get the notification for every 30 seconds. How can I achieve this? I do not want to perform this activity for particular button.

Comment: use Service class

Comment: @DivyeshPatel Can u provide me any link?

Comment: You want this for the actual push notification(firebase) or for the local notification ? please clarify what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Local notification. I am getting all the data through api @AJ--

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42870620/6756514

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved screen refresh using **Runnable Handler**. Once I did that, I updated the old status with set method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **AlarmReceiver** class for achieving this thing.

Follow this link : https://www.sitepoint.com/scheduling-background-tasks-android/

Refrence :

**1. Create BroadcastReceiver :**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // For our recurring task, we'll just display a message
        Toast.makeText(arg0, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
 }
```

2. Declare   it in **AndroidManifeast** file as below :

   ```
   <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
   ```
3. In your **java file** or **Activity** class  :

   in **onCreate()** method, declare and initialize Intent alarmIntent:

`Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
     pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);`

4. create below mwthod and then call it :

   ```
   public void startAlarm(View view) {
       manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
       int interval = 10000;
       manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
       Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
   ```